# Using async with .Net 4 and ms.bcl.async

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await

I've imported ms.bcl.async nuget package with my .Net 4 project and started to write code using async/await. I've got strange error message trying to await a Task returning method.
[image]

I'm at a loss here since .Result() works, but await does not. Also this code is supposed to run on Windows Azure 1.8 (old SDK version). Got no ideas how to proceed unfortunately.

How it compiles (did not test yet):
[image]

Comment: That is because the return type of client.SendAsync() is void..

Comment: Nope, problem is in the await keyword. See the second picture. The return value is awaitable Task<HttpResponseMessage>

Comment: What VS Project is this? Class Library?

Comment: The return type of your anonymous Lamba expression there..?
Should it be async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ()=> instead of async ()=>

Comment: How are you getting `HttpClient` on .NET 4.0? did you install the MSFT package from NuGet?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Output : Class Library, Target Framework : .Net 4. Its a web project. Can you be more specific about MSFT please?

Comment: @bit Lambda is not to blame - same error when problem code is moved out of it.

Comment: I would clean my solution, remove references, add them again and re-build as a first attempt.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Man, clean worked, please add and answer if you wish and I will select it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in the comments, this looks like a a build issue more than a library issue.
I would clean and re-build my solution as a first attempt at fixing these kind of problems.